# Commit reword without interactive rebase?

Tags: git

Is it possible to run an automatic reword of a commit (identified by hash) without using interactive mode? What I aim for is a one-liner for rewording because I need to invoke from code.

UPDATE:

I modified it a little for inline use.

`git filter-branch --msg-filter "ruby -e \"puts (ENV['GIT_COMMIT'] == '1ba2dd66581f6fbc03d1a6406a0ed61b6473c9ab' ? 'new msg' : STDIN.read)\"" HEAD`

Would be nice though in pure bash (without ruby), but I had troubles with getting the STDIN to work (using read).

Comment: You could reset to the commit, do an amend to change the commit comment, and then cherry-pick each of the commits following it from the original branch. But it seems like there's gotta be an easier way than that.

Comment: It looks like [`git-filter-branch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-filter-branch) could be of use, specifically the `--msg-filter` option. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell it which commit to rewrite.

Comment: If you're trying to do this in pure bash, I don't know how to do the conditional logic, but for the 'if' case you could use `echo` and for the 'else' case you could use `cat -` to just copy STDIN to STDOUT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`git-filter-branch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-filter-branch) can do what you want. Specifically, you want the `--msg-filter` argument:

> This is the filter for rewriting the commit messages. The argument is evaluated in the shell with the original commit message on standard input; its standard output is used as the new commit message.

One wrinkle is that `git-filter-branch` wants to run on *every* commit in the branch, while you only want to rewrite *one* commit (and then effectively rebase the rest). So your message filter needs to have some conditional logic, to output either the new commit comment (for the one commit you actually do want to rewrite), or the original, unmodified commit message (for everything else).

This does the trick:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter "ruby /path/to/filter.rb 843c2da5e07de914ea2319fa3295730ff8b3b0a1 'New message'" HEAD
```

`git-filter-branch` changes the current directory before it invokes your script, so you do need to fully qualify `/path/to/filter.rb`.

Here's `filter.rb`:

```
if ENV['GIT_COMMIT'] == ARGV[0]
  puts ARGV[1]
else
  puts STDIN.read
end
```

This could probably be rewritten more succinctly in shell script, perhaps without even putting the message-filter script in a separate file; but I'm running on Windows so I don't have anything that fancy. I do have Ruby, so I used that, and it does work.

Comment: great one! note though that the semantics of a hash code is changed slightly here: `git` usually complains if a hashcode is ambiguous; your code seems to be changing all the commits for an ambiguous hashcode. Not a problem, just something to keep in mind: better safe than sorry.

Comment: @alf, I didn't even think about two commits having the same 7-character hex prefix -- you're absolutely right that this would have undesired effects in that case. I changed my code to require the full hash, for safety's sake. If OP is invoking this programmatically, then the full hash is probably available anyway.